# Standard function for negative one to the N, where N is an integer

Tags: python, scipy

This applies to any language really, but I am currently using python and scipy.

I know there is an easy way to do it. Just something like `1 - 2*(N & 1)` would do it. But that's hard to read, and there might be a standard function for it somewhere already.

Comment: why is wrong with using the power operator?

Comment: Python's a**N operator is O(N) (O(log N) at the very best if they used a good algorithm) when a and N are integers, but (-1)**N is order 1 with a method like 1 - 2*(N & 1). I doubt the developers specialised a**N to that extent. A problem like this is best treated with a specialised function like the exp() function is.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want correctly, raising negative one to the power of N:

```
print (-1) ** N
```

Comment: I think his question was if there is some functionthat can be used so that it does not have to rais to the power

Answer (score 2):

In python, you do powers with the `**` operator.  So yes, there is a standard function (well, operator) for it and it is very easy to read.

So for your example you could just for example:

```
>>> N = 3
>>> value = (-1) ** N
>>> print(value)
-1
```

Or if you don't want to use operators but rather a function you can do:

```
>>> import math
>>> N = 3
>>> value = math.pow((-1), 3)
>>> print(value)
-1
```

However, this seems pointless as `-1` to the power of anything will always equal `-1` if it is odd and 1 if it is even.

Comment: 1 to the power of anything is 1 but -1 to an even power is 1 while to an odd power is -1.

Comment: Why the downvote? I answered the question correctly did I not. I also make it that for example `-1 ^ 4` is still `-1`.

Comment: downvote because it's just plain wrong. -1 ^4 and (-1)^4 is not the same.

Comment: That would call for a comment like the first, not a downvote which is completely unconstructive and uncalled for. @M4rtini

Comment: Unconstructive, probably. uncalled for, not so much as there was a obvious error. And the last statement in this answer is still wrong. "1 to the power of anything.." should be " -1 to the power of anything.."

Comment: Read what it says when you hover your mouse over the downvote arrow. My answer was relevant and correct, just a detail was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Python's version of a ternary operator let's you write it as:

```
-1 if n % 2 else 1
```

which is a nice and readable one liner.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are asking if there is an easy way to define this so as to not have to actually use exponent arithmetic.

```
def minusone(n)
  if n%2 == 0:
    retval = 1
  else;
    retval = -1
  return retval
```

Your original suggestion might be better as

```
1 - 2*(n%2)
```